# In the context of 'matches' stored in a database, may I say "We do predictions using **this** matches data"?

Tags: grammaticality

I have problem of using articles, and don`t know or correct is use **this** pronoun in sentence below:

> Here you can found all matches  stored in company database. We do predictions using **this** matches data.

Matches is plural of word  match.

Based on some comments, I have revised my sentence:

> Here you can *find* all matches stored in *a* company database. We do predictions using this collected data.

Comment: Both the sentences you quote are very ungrammatical. The second one would be grammatical if you write _matched_ instead of _matches_ (although some would insist that _data_ is plural and it should therefore be _these data_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The first one is **grammatical** (although it does need an article before "company database") but using the verb *to found* doesn't make a great deal of sense

Comment: @AndrewLeach It was mostly the missing article I was referring to, though I admit _to found_ didn’t cross my mind at all.

Comment: What about these sentences: Here you can *find* all matches  stored in *an* company database. We do predictions using collected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here you can find all matches stored in the company database. We do predictions using this ***matched*** data.

(When used as an adjective modifying *data*, we use the word *matched*.)

(As others pointed out, it's "Here you can find," not "Here you can found".)

We could also change the subject to *we* instead of *you*:

> Here **we** can find all matches stored in the company database. We do predictions using this *matched* data.

But enough of all that. Your question was about the word **this**.

---

That's a tricky question, because the sentence can be written with that word *omitted*, or with that word *included*. Both sentences would be grammatical, and both would mean almost the same thing:

> Here we can find all matches stored in the company database. We do predictions using matched data.
>
> Here we can find all matches stored in the company database. We do predictions using this matched data.

The first sentence says that the company does predictions based on data matches in the database.

The second sentence says that the company does predictions using the data matches found in the database.

The difference is almost imperceptible because of the tense you've used in your sentence. If the company regularly looks for matches and then does predictions based on the matches that are found, either one can be used.

However, if we change the second sentence to past tense, and we are talking about the set of matches we just found, then the sentence reads better with the "this" included:

> Here we have found all matches stored in the company database. We did predictions using matched data.
>
> Here we have found all matches stored in the company database. We did predictions using this matched data.

If we are talking about very specific predictions done on very specific data (that is, the data we just found), we can indicate that by leaving the "this" in.